# Mono Cecil get delegate method argument

Tags: reflection, delegates, mono.cecil

I have a very simple assembly below. I'm trying to use Mono.Cecil to reflect over it to find the parameter passed to all calls to CallApiAsync. When I
isolate the MethodReference for the call I cannot seem to get the parameter  **`x.GetResponse(new SomeRequestType())`**, I just get the delegate definition **`ApiMethodAsync<T, TResult>`**. I've drawn a blank on this, any help appreciated.

```
public class ApiWrapper
{
 public delegate Task<TResult> ApiMethodAsync<T, TResult>(T api);

 public virtual async Task<SomeResponseType> MakeSomeRequestToApi() 
 {
    return await CallApiAsync<ISomeApi, SomeResponseType>(x => x.GetResponse(new SomeRequestType()));
 }

 public virtual async Task<TResult> CallApiAsync<T, TResult>(ApiMethodAsync<T, TResult> apiMethod) where TResult : new()
 {
    return await Task.FromResult(new TResult());
 }
}

public interface ISomeApi
{
    Task<SomeResponseType> GetResponse(SomeRequestType request);
}

public class SomeResponseType { }
public class SomeRequestType { }
```

Below is the Mono Cecil code I am using to identify calls to CallApiAsync

```
var moduleDefinition = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule("SimpleAssembly.dll");

var targetClass = moduleDefinition.Types.Where(t => t.FullName.Contains("ApiWrapper")).Single();

            var nestedMethodInstructions = targetClass.NestedTypes
                                                      .SelectMany(p => p.Methods)
                                                      .Where(m => m.HasBody)
                                                      .SelectMany(t => t.Body.Instructions).ToList();

            foreach (var instr in nestedMethodInstructions)
            {
                if (instr.Operand != null)
                {
                    var methodRef = instr.Operand as MethodReference;

                    if (methodRef != null && methodRef.FullName.Contains("CallApiAsync"))
                    {
                        // Get the full delegate parameter, ie  GetResponse(new SomeRequestType())
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: So let me get this straight; you want to intercept all calls to the `CallApiAsync` method and save the parameters passed to it?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to capture the Generic arguments and the lambda expression passed in as an argument

Answer (score 1):

There's gonna be my clue on how to do what you want, but I didn't managed to do it yet. The problem is, that async/await is a syntax sugar, so both your **MakeSomeRequestToApi**  and **CallApi** methods are expanded by compiler to the following code (there goes MakeSomeRequestToApi and CallApi looks pretty much the same):

```
[CompilerGenerated]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
private struct <MakeSomeRequestToApi>d__2 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
        public int <>1__state;

        public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<SomeResponseType> <>t__builder;

        public ApiWrapper <>4__this;

        private TaskAwaiter<SomeResponseType> <>u__$awaiter3;

        private object <>t__stack;

        void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
        {
            SomeResponseType result;
            try
            {
                int num = this.<>1__state;
                if (num != -3)
                {
                    TaskAwaiter<SomeResponseType> taskAwaiter;
                    if (num != 0)
                    {
                        ApiWrapper arg_43_0 = this.<>4__this;
                        if (ApiWrapper.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 == null)
                        {
                            ApiWrapper.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = new ApiWrapper.ApiMethodAsync<ISomeApi, SomeResponseType>(ApiWrapper.<MakeSomeRequestToApi>b__0);
                        }
                        taskAwaiter = arg_43_0.CallApiAsync<ISomeApi, SomeResponseType>(ApiWrapper.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1).GetAwaiter();
                        if (!taskAwaiter.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            this.<>1__state = 0;
                            this.<>u__$awaiter3 = taskAwaiter;
                            this.<>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TaskAwaiter<SomeResponseType>, ApiWrapper.<MakeSomeRequestToApi>d__2>(ref taskAwaiter, ref this);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        taskAwaiter = this.<>u__$awaiter3;
                        this.<>u__$awaiter3 = default(TaskAwaiter<SomeResponseType>);
                        this.<>1__state = -1;
                    }
                    SomeResponseType arg_A8_0 = taskAwaiter.GetResult();
                    taskAwaiter = default(TaskAwaiter<SomeResponseType>);
                    result = arg_A8_0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.<>1__state = -2;
                this.<>t__builder.SetException(exception);
                return;
            }
            this.<>1__state = -2;
            this.<>t__builder.SetResult(result);
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine param0)
        {
            this.<>t__builder.SetStateMachine(param0);
        }
    }
```

In the middle of a structure there is a line

```
ApiWrapper.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = new ApiWrapper.ApiMethodAsync<ISomeApi, SomeResponseType>(ApiWrapper.<MakeSomeRequestToApi>b__0);
```

Which in the source code looks like:

```
CallApiAsync<ISomeApi, SomeResponseType>(x => x.GetResponse(new SomeRequestType()));
```

And the parameter passed in the constructor, which is in the end of a line is:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
    private static Task<SomeResponseType> <MakeSomeRequestToApi>b__0(ISomeApi x)
    {
        return x.GetResponse(new SomeRequestType());
    }
```

So, in conclussion, I'm sure it is possible to look up all this things in operands and instructions, but async/await and delegates make it hell of a work. Hope I helped a little.

P.S.
The code has been decompiled by ILSpy tool, with "Decompile async methods" option switched off